# How can i open links in default browser, in my Google extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-apps

I have a Chrome App (url bar less) and an my custom extension installed in that app.

Use of extension is to handle links click inside the app.
I want **some links on all websites in my chrome app to open through Default browser window,** not inside my app and other links to open inside my app.

Currently, on clicking links, it creates new window, but its an app window not of the default browser.

I have tried

`chrome.windows.getAll` to get all the windows id present, then

`chrome.tabs.create(windowId,{url:url})`

but it only gives me windows created by my Chrome app.

Is there anyway to do create tabs inside default browser (Chrome) not the app itself ?

Comment: Updated question. Please check.

Comment: Is chrome.browser api available to extension also ?

Comment: I think I understand finally the setup. You have a browser-like app that supports extensions. There's no built-in solution so you'll need to use [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to launch a separate utility (you can write it in python or node.js or C), pass the URL to it in a message, and it'll run the system's default browser.